# Is it a good practice to pass iterable list to a page as a parameter?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am preparing an XML request body using a page and to avoid controller I am thinking to pass a iterable list.

**Example:**

```
PageReference aPage = Page.XYZPage;
aPage.getParameters().put('id', accountId);
aPage.getParameters().put('qlid', **lstOfIds or lstOfAccount**);
```

This page is used for preparing SOAP request body not to launch from any button. So, is it a good practice to pass iterable list as a param?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more in detail, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually pass anything other than a String through a page parameter, so your page will still need to parse the list of values somehow. Visualforce itself doesn't have any way to split the string apart, so you'd need either Apex or JavaScript to do so. Given that this is supposed to be called as an API, this means you need Apex in order to get at what you're trying to do.

So, generally speaking, this probably a Bad Idea to begin with. You may want to use wsdl2apex to create a SOAP interface, rather than dealing with a Visualforce page, which will also suffer from other limitations, as calling a Visualforce page is considered a callout (meaning, you can't do so after a DML, you can't call it indefinitely, etc).